# JSON parsed object into a javascript function : syntaxerror

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

I am working on parsing a json script queried through ajax from my database. I want to use what I queried (in a json format) in my javascript function "addComp()" that adds a geometric component for each building on a map. Here is the jQuery/ajax code:

```
$.ajax({ 

        type: "GET",
        url: "ajax_processor.php",
        dataType : "json",

        success:function(data){ 
        console.log(data); //here I got what i want

        var geometryElement = $.parseJSON(data);

                for (var i=0; i<geometryElement.length; i++) {
                      addComp(  geometryElement[i].bldg, 
                                    geometryElement[i].iZ, 
                                    geometryElement[i].iType,
                                    geometryElement[i].x0,
                                    geometryElement[i].y0,
                                    geometryElement[i].p, ...); //parameters p1, p2, p3, p4, p5
                 }
        }
});
```

The JSON script I got, queried through PHP is :

```
{"ID_geometryElement":"1","bldg":"1","iZ":"1","iType":"1","x0":"23","y0":"5","p1":"5","p2":"2","p3":"3","p4":"0","p5":"0"},
{"ID_geometryElement":"2","bldg":"1","iZ":"1","iType":"1","x0":"24","y0":"7","p1":"2.5","p2":"4","p3":"3.5","p4":"0","p5":"0"},
 ...
```

But that doesn't display anything on the map, and I got the following errors:

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o          jquery.js:550
 jQuery.extend.parseJSON                           jquery.js:550    
 $.ajax.success                                    index_LF.php:3725
 fire                                              jquery.js:3074
 self.fireWith                                     jquery.js:3186
 done                                              jquery.js:8253
 callback                                          jquery.js:8796
 handleStateChange                                 firebug-lite.js:18917
```

Does anyone know where it comes from and how to fix it ?

EDIT: on the PHP side, I got :

```
    <?php

    $host = 'localhost';
    $databaseName = 'localdb';
    $tableName = 'building_geometry';
    $user = 'admin';
    $password = 'password';


    $connexion = mysql_connect($host,$user,$password);
    $dbs = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $connexion);

    $sql = mysql_query('SELECT * from building_geometry');

    $rows = array();
    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
        $rows[] = $r;
    }

    echo json_encode($rows);

    ?>
```

but the problem is not in the php, I was parsing twice what was already in json (dataType is json).

Comment: The error is probably on the PHP side. It's probably not returning valid javascript, possibly by not escaping something like a `'` or `"` properly. The javascript code seems valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not valid JSON.  It looks like an array literal but it's missing the outer square brackets.

That is,

```
{"foo": 0, ... },
{"bar": 1, ... },
```

is invalid, but it would be valid if it were

```
[{"foo": 0, ... },
{"bar": 1, ... }]
```

Anyway, if you're telling jQuery that the data type is JSON, and it really *is* JSON, then you don't have to parse it. The "data" parameter will be the parsed object, not the unparsed string.

Comment: I have in fact the outer square brackets you are talking about, I was just displaying a sample of what I got. but maybe my question was not clear : did i do something wrong in the "data" parameter like using is as an array in the line "geometryElement[i].bldg" for example ?
EDIT: Yes, you were right, no need to parse it, I thought I had to. I got it. Thanks a lot !

Comment: This really helped me, but I'm wondering why the square brackets are not being added to my output inspite of using json_encode. I could just output them manually...

Comment: @aalaap that's a good question; I'm not a PHP coder so I don't know why it would do that.